# Infinite digest loop in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I try to get param value from properties. I created some variable in angular:

```
var someVar = false;
```

and then, using method below I try to get one param from backend endpoint:

```
 function isActive() {
            Configuration.get(function (result) {
                someVar = result.isActive;
            });

            return someVar;
        }
```

This Configuration call backend and get my param but I have this error:
https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/docs/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
How to fix this?